# Space between two elements in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a recyclerview for a list.
There is some unwanted space between two elements of list. I haven't done anything for space.

Code for Recyclerview in xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rv_content_list"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/collapsing_layout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
             />
```

code for raw layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_raw_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center|left"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_raw_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="visible"
                />

            <VideoView
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:id="@+id/vv_raw_video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_raw_caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_raw_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:text=""/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output image:[image]

AS image:

[image: now i have set black color to whole b]ackground.

how to remove that space??

Comment: Hi ! In your example, you seem to have 3 TextViews, but only 2 display in the SS. Are you sure that android:id="@+id/tv_raw_info" is set or needed ? Its parent has a marginTop of 10dp, and even if it is empty, the margin would still be there.

Comment: You have added android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

Comment: @RazvanGabriel yes info text is inside the imageview's relativelayout and aligned bottom. I also tried by removing that whole textview, but no improvement :(

Comment: @RajeshTiwari yes its inside linearlayout. And also removing this doesn't do anything :(

Comment: @kiturk3 try and remove  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" from     android:id="@+id/tv_raw_caption" . Either that or the RelativeLayout is too big with 150dp. maybe go with minHeight. Just trying different things. Also, try to give different backgrounds to your items, to see which one extends too much.

Comment: @RazvanGabriel nope... no luck... still same :(

Comment: @kiturk3 areyou giving "demo 3rd text" any value ? It could be empty! Give it a default value, run the app and see than. Also, you are not using any decorations for your recyclerview in java right?

Comment: @RazvanGabriel yes see the last edit... i have given default text now. and no i am not using any decorations as if now